# use same route for nested pages svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a page with nested routes, for which I'd like to use the same template. The routes could look like this:

```bash
/foo
/foo/bar
```

This nesting is for ordering and internal reasons only. I want them to use the same template, i.e. I want it to be like this:

```bash
/src/routes/[foo]/+page.svelte # only this route needed
/src/routes/[foo]/[bar]/+page.svelte # use the upper template instead
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

This sound like a case for [optional parameters](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#optional-parameters), you would just define one route:

```
/src/routes/[foo]/[[bar]]/+page.svelte
```

`bar` is optional so `/foo` and `/foo/bar` should lead to the same route.

Alternatively, if this does not cover the full real case, you can always extract the entire page content to a separate component and import that or define a [`+layout.svelte`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-layout-svelte) at the upper level that contains everything the routes have in common.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible to use the same template for nested routes in a Svelte application